# Mirror / Synchronize sda - sdb / while running server

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive, backup, sync

My current scenario is that, I am using Ubuntu Linux 14.04.1 Server.
Servers Installed 
   Apache Webserver
   BIND DNS Server
   Dovecot IMAP/POP3 Server
   MySQL Database Server
   Postfix Mail Server
   PostgreSQL Database Server
   Procmail Mail Filter
   ProFTPD Server
   Read User Mail
   Samba Windows File Sharing
   SSH Server
   Virtualmin Virtual Servers (GPL)
   Webalizer Logfile Analysis

There are two hard drives attached sda/500Gb & sdb/500Gb

Mostly i use webmin for system configuration.

Please someone tell me how to synchronize full data sda to sdb while running my server.
Just like mirror Hard Drive. and Mirror on daily basis. I want to make it like if sda failed then sdb take it's place.

Sorry for my bad English.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [RAID](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/raid-levels-tutorial/).

More: you need RAID-1. There are various types, you can read up on the Internet about how to set up your hard drives in these combinations.

Comment: "you can read about it on the internet" is not an answer.

Comment: It looked like he hadn't done the basic research - he didn't even mention RAID anywhere. So I pointed him to the right direction. Agreed, it could have been a comment.

Comment: Also, I believe we dont need user manuals as answers in AskUbuntu.

Comment: @SiddharthaRT thanks man. That is what i really want, a starting point. :) and i am glad that everyone else gave such a positive help.